# Importing iPhoto over wireless

Tags: mac, photos.app

I'd like to copy all photos from one iPhoto album (on `machine A`) onto a new iPhoto library (on `machine B`). I realise I could import the *physical* folder over a share but **I'd like to keep the event folders** etc and **not import the original and modified duplicates** within the source library.

The folder size is around 15GB and I was able to select import from within iPhoto and point it to the remote iPhoto location on `machine B`. It attempted to import all night and when I got up, it reported there wasn't enough disk space to do the import. Machine A had about 75GB so I suspect something else.

Anyway, my question is really to see if you have any tips about copying or otherwise sharing photos between machines. If you've got any insight in what went wrong for my scenario above, I'd love to hear that too!

Machine B is a Macbook Air and has no ethernet port, hence the wireless tag.

**EDIT** If I were to export then import, I'd lose the event groups wouldn't I? I want to keep what organisation I have between the machines.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [iPhoto Library Manager](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/), it copies the images *and* events, it even does *faces*.

Well pleased with the result, handled 17GB library no problem across my wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the images from Machine A to the Finder, then import that to machine B.

There's no other way to do it that won't get edited versions etc.